# How to remove and clear all localStorage data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I need to clear all data i set into `localStorage`. By this, I mean completely reset `localStorage` to `null` when users remove their accounts.

How can i do that with a simple function?

I tried this:

```
function clearLocalStorage(){
    return localStorage= null;
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Just in case it helps someone, the code above is wrong in many ways. First of all, the `=` operator is meant to be used in a sentence, and the result shouldn't be used as an expression (look for differences between sentence and expression, two concepts that are related). Also, assigning null to a variable  clears the value of it, but not necessarily clears the object that it contains from the memory (e.g. if the object is referenced by other variables).

Answer (score 537, accepted):

`localStorage.clear();`

should work.

Comment: window.localStorage.clear(); //if working on ionic i.e

Comment: sessionStorage.clear(); to remove session storage data.

Comment: In some cases you might need to call it from the window object `window.localStorage.clear();`

Answer (score 115):

If you want to remove/clean all the values from local storage than use

```
localStorage.clear();
```

And if you want to remove the specific item from local storage than use the following code

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

Comment: Hi, @Talha. If I don't want to remove for a particular item then is there a way to do it too? For example 'removeItemNotIn(key)'.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figured out a solution for my problem:- 

if(localStorage.getItem(particularKey) == null){
   localStorage.clear();   
  }  
But if you have a better solution then do let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

It only worked for me in Firefox when accessing it from the `window` object.

Example...

```
window.onload = function()
{
 window.localStorage.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `.one` ensures this is done only once and not repeatedly.

```
$(window).one("focus", function() {
    localStorage.clear();
});
```

It is okay to put several document.ready event listeners (if you need other events to execute multiple times) as long as you do not overdo it, for the sake of readability.

`.one` is especially useful when you want local storage to be cleared only once the first time a web page is opened or when a mobile application is installed the first time.

```
   // Fired once when document is ready
   $(document).one('ready', function () {
       localStorage.clear();
   });
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do:

```
function cleanLocalStorage() {
    for(key in localStorage) {
        delete localStorage[key];
    }
}
```

Be careful about using this, though, as the user may have other data stored in `localStorage` and would probably be pretty ticked if you deleted that. I'd recommend either a) not storing the user's data in `localStorage` or b) storing the user's account stuff in a single variable,  and then clearing that instead of deleting all the keys in `localStorage`.

---

**Edit**: As Lyn pointed out, you'll be good with `localStorage.clear()`. My previous points still stand, however.