# How to clear Local Storage from client whenever i publish new code

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I have build my application on Angular 4 and I am using local storage to store user session. What I want is whenever I publish my application, user local Storage should get reset so that data before release should not create any problem.

How do i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clearing localStorage in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667958/clearing-localstorage-in-javascript)

Comment: in jQuery - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710674/html5-localstorage-remove-and-clear-all-data

Comment: @VTodorov I think, you didn't understand what he wants.

Comment: @NnN jQuery has nothing to do with `localStorage` and none of the answers in the link has any reference to jQuery O.o

Comment: you have to write the script with version update whenever new version is less than current clear local storage but he will make the user to log out, 1 st time, you cant do this on publishing code, it's client side  so it will be updated when user open site

Comment: @Andreas - I could see one answer!

Comment: @NnN Yes and no. That one answer only uses jQuery to wait for the page to load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using versioning, keep an extra key at client side which will be having the last version. If version matches then it means no new code has been published, if version doesn't match which tells that new code has been passed, then just have a utility which will clear the local-storage.

Comment: that way i have to ensure each time that version should be update to +1 or can it be done with angular project version in package json.

Comment: have a global constant which you can update each time you are publishing, considering you are using some build scripts.

Comment: i will be updating package.json file with new version each time and then checking that with the old session.

Comment: @PraveenRawat exactly. Try to include this in Build tool itself so that it becomes automated.

Answer (score 6):

Use **app versioning**.

**Disclaimer: THIS SOLUTION IS NOT FOR WINDOWS USER!**

The best practice is to automate the versioning so that you don't have to manually set the app version again and again.

The idea is to

1. Get the current git SHA, if no older SHA found, store it in the localstorage.
2. If older SHA found, compare the SHAs, if not equal, clear the storage, set the new SHA in localstorage.

This will give you the current short version of the current commit SHA.

`git rev-parse --short HEAD`

In your **package.json**

```
"scripts": {     
      "build": "REACT_APP_CURRENT_GIT_SHA=`git rev-parse --short HEAD` react-scripts build",     
      "start": "REACT_APP_CURRENT_GIT_SHA=`git rev-parse --short HEAD` react-scripts start" 
 }
```

in the code, we get this variable through

```
process.env.REACT_APP_CURRENT_GIT_SHA
```

Code:

```
const APP_VERSION = process.env.REACT_APP_CURRENT_GIT_SHA;

if (typeof localStorage.APP_VERSION === 'undefined' || localStorage.APP_VERSION === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('APP_VERSION', APP_VERSION);
}

if (localStorage.APP_VERSION != APP_VERSION) {
    localStorage.clear();
}`
```

Comment: It helped me, thx! I would also add, that in the package.json I use
`"scripts": {
    "build": "REACT_APP_CURRENT_GIT_SHA=\`git rev-parse --short HEAD\` react-scripts build",
    "start": "REACT_APP_CURRENT_GIT_SHA=\`git rev-parse --short HEAD\` react-scripts start",
}`

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/tunaiku-tech/automate-javascript-project-versioning-with-commitizen-and-standard-version-6a967afae7) about `app versioning` is way more better.

Answer (score 1):

You could store a version string in your application and in the local storage.
On your app startup you check if the string in localStorage matches the string in your application. If not, clear the local storage.

Comment: Thanks man for reply but I was thinking to automate this thing. So that i do not have to go through the pain of release.

Answer (score 0):

config/app.php

```
return [
        'version'         => env('APP_VERSION', "1.0.0"),
```

In ***.blade.php

```
<script>
    var version_app = "{{ config('app.version') }}"
</script>
```

Add to **.js

```
if(typeof localStorage.version_app === 'undefined' || localStorage.version_app === null) {
        localStorage.setItem('version_app', version_app);
    }
if(localStorage.version_app != version_app){
            localStorage.clear();
    }
```

When you change the version, the script automatically deletes the localStorage data

Answer (score 0):

**MULTI-PLATFORM USE CASES and OPTIONAL STORAGE CLEARING** (following Paras answer).

Since the script shell for npm is CMD.exe by default and since CMD.exe does not support command substitution.

By command substitution, I mean this syntax which takes the return value for a command and uses it as an argument for another

```
REACT_APP_CURRENT_GIT_SHA=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
```

The workaround that worked for me was to change the script shell for npm to bash by running this in powershell

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Note that you need to have git installed

And then using [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) so I can use a single syntax for both linux and windows platforms

My package.json script ended up looking like this

```
{
    "start": "cross-env REACT_APP_CURRENT_GIT_SHA=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) REACT_APP_CLEAR_STORAGE=${npm_config_clear_storage} react-scripts start",
    "build": "cross-env REACT_APP_CURRENT_GIT_SHA=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) REACT_APP_CLEAR_STORAGE=${npm_config_clear_storage} react-scripts build"
}
```

I added `REACT_APP_CLEAR_STORAGE=${npm_config_clear_storage}` so I could manually specify when running the scripts if I wanted the localStorage to get cleared. (If you do not want this, do not add it)

*Note that the extra argument works when the version (REACT_APP_CURRENT_GIT_SHA) changes only*

My code now looks like this

```
const APP_VERSION = process.env.REACT_APP_CURRENT_GIT_SHA;
const CLEAR_STORAGE = !!process.env.REACT_APP_CLEAR_STORAGE;

if (localStorage.APP_VERSION != APP_VERSION) {
    if (CLEAR_STORAGE) {
        localStorage.clear();
    }
    localStorage.setItem("APP_VERSION", APP_VERSION);
}
```

And to run **build** and clear localStorage, I do `npm run build --clear_storage`

Meanwhile, to run **build** without clearing localStorage, I just do `npm run build`